# PHP Function that Randomly Selects One mySQL Row With A Unix Date of Less than Two Weeks

Tags: random, unix-timestamp

I need a php function that can randomly select one row that has a unix time date field (like 2011-11-12 or 2011-12-24) that indicates the row was created within the last two weeks from a mySQL table and return the id of that said row.

I don't know how do this. Honestly, I would like someone to hand me the code, but I don't like that because most people don't like that.. and their reasons make sense, but if someone would show me the code, then please do, thus can someone at the least point me in the right direction? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date by using `date` and `strtotime`:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks"));
```

Then the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field >= '$date' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

`ORDER BY RAND()` gives you a random row.

`strtotime`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Ok thanks, I came up with this code: `require("cms/connection.php"); $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks")); $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE publicationDate >= '$date' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo "Title:" . $row['title'] . "<br />"; echo "Caption:" . $row['caption'] . "<br />"; } echo "End"; mysql_close($connection);` There is a problem. It is giving me this error: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource. I think result is returning false but I can't find the error.

Comment: I found some errors so I fixed them. Here is my revised code: $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-2 weeks")); $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `publicationDate` >= '$date' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;"); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))               Yet I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Hmm. I'd suggest printing out mysql_error(), to see what the error is. You'd do that right after the call to mysql_query().